# How to rotate svg circle to follow the click/touch?

Tags: jquery, svg, rotation, rotatetransform

I have svg circles, rotating by mousemove and need to rotate them by doubleclick/doubletap.

My function for rotate looks like this:

```
function rotateCirc(id, coords) {
    var parentN = $('#rus-circular');
    var ctm = $('#'+id).parent().parent()[0].getScreenCTM();
    var p = parentN[0].createSVGPoint();
    p.x = coords[0];
    p.y = coords[1];
    p = p.matrixTransform(ctm.inverse());
    var radians = Math.atan2(1990 - p.x, 1900 - p.y);
    var degrees = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
    $('#'+id).css('transform','rotate('+degrees+'deg)');
}
```

where `coords` is clientX and clientY click coordinates

But rotation work wrong, I need to rotate the "hole" of circle where i'm clicked;

How to rich there?

**My demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2of73or/4/**